# Extracting the contents of an HTML page element using Python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am given a link to an HTML page. How can I open it and get the content of a particular element using its absolute XPath.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://www.professorpaddle.com/rivers/riverlist.asp')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
table_data=[]
temp_dict={}
temp = tree.xpath('//a[@class="pathm"]')
for i in temp:
  link=i.attrib.get('href')
  link="http://www.professorpaddle.com/rivers/"+link
  temp_dict['name']=i.text
  temp_dict['link']=link
  print(link)
  temp_page=requests.get(link)
  temp_tree=html.fromstring(temp_page.content)
  x=temp_tree.xpath('/html/body/element/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/font')
  print(x)
  break
```

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: yes but how can i post my code ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: x=temp_tree.xpath('/html/body/element/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/font')

Comment: What are you trying to recover from that page?

Comment: Main Page contains some links.I have extracted them . Each Link contains a table.Now going to the links one by one,I have to collect data from that table

Comment: One of my more stupid questions! I should have asked, on a typical page which table are you trying to pick up? For instance, on http://www.professorpaddle.com/rivers/riverdetails.asp?riverid=350 I see one called 'Gauge', another called 'Take out'.

Comment: And what do you want from within the table?

Answer (score 1):

xpath could not seem to find the tbody's. I also sought to simplify the xpath search string to make it easier for myself. When I did that it wasn't long before I found that there are two spellings for one of the classes. Here's what I have for one page.

```
>>> URL = 'http://www.professorpaddle.com/rivers/riverdetails.asp?riverid=350'
>>> from lxml import html
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get(URL)
>>> tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
>>> tableRows = tree.xpath('..//table[@class="tableBorder" or @class="tableborder"][2]/tr')
>>> len(tableRows)
2
>>> for row in tableRows:
...     for child in row.iterchildren():
...         if child.text:
...             child.text.strip()
...             
'Pinned Forum Threads'
''
''
```

Almost forgot, I'd have preferred to use **matches** over the **or** but apparently the xpath in this implementation doesn't offer regex.

Supplement, in response to a comment:

```
>>> fontItems = tree.xpath('..//table[@class="tableBorder" or @class="tableborder"][1]/tr/td/font[@class="path"]')
>>> len(fontItems)
12
>>> for item in fontItems:
...     list(item.itertext())
...     
['GPS/GIS']
['Maps']
['Put In Longitude : ']
['-121.29268']
['Put In Latitude : ']
['47.8034515']
['Take Out Longitude : ']
['-121.33998']
['Take Out Latitude : ']
['47.7137985']
['County : ']
['Snohomish']
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949270/extracting-just-sibling-element-in-xpath

Comment: please answer this question

Comment: This is correct but you please try to answer that question.It will solve my problem