# extracting just-sibling element in xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

[image: Image of the page source]

I am using this line of code to select this element

x=temp_tree.xpath('//font[text()="Put In Longitude : "]/just-sibling::td/font/text()')

It is giving an error.
Please Correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> thingy = tree.xpath('..//font[text()="Put In Latitude : "]/../following-sibling::td/font/text()')
>>> thingy
['47.8034515']
```

The font you selected doesn't have a sibling. Go back up the tree to the parent td with .. and then down to find the sibling td containing the required item.